# Оставить только onclick

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, синтаксический-анализ

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup('reg', 580, 400)" class="ssbutton"></a>
```

как распарсить через PHP  тег <а> чтобы получить `onclick` ?

разумно ли использовать  `preg_match_all`?

или есть по проще вариант?

```
preg_match_all('@onclick="(.*)"@Ui', $service["FORM_HTML"], $m);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254616/regular-expression-to-extract-the-onclick-value-from-a-string

Comment: смешивать фронтэнд и бэкэнд не хорошо, задача скорее всего может быть решена иным, нормальным способом, а не в лоб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярка: `/<a.*?onclick=["']*["']*.*?>(.*?)<\/a.*?>/si`